# The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. in VS2015 Professional

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I've opened my solution in VS2015 Professional.  I'm getting errors for some (but not all) projects:

> The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML
> namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format,
> please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
> to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old
> 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

I unloaded and viewed csproj with the error and see the  tag already has this:

```html
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

I'm using .NET 4.6.2 and have the same nuget packages as a coworker, who's also running VS2015 Professional.  They don't have this error.

I've seen other posts which suggest I should get VS2017 which will fix it.  However, this isn't an option at this time.  How can I fix this without upgrading?

Comment: Check the Target version of Net that is being used to build application.  Even though you have Net 4.6.2 you can target older version of Net.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but perhaps you need to change to use/set `ToolsVersion="14.0"`. (VS 2015 > 14.0, VS 2017 > 15.0)

This document: [How the ToolsVersion attribute works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion?view=vs-2019#how-the-toolsversion-attribute-works) may be helpful.